# setInterval only runs once with subscription.on

Tags: javascript, node.js, setinterval

I have a node script that I use to store data from some microsensors and I was writing a setInterval function and noticed that it was only running for the first 3 or so seconds of the script. I was able to isolate the bug to the subscirption.on portion of my script.

```
const subscription = pubsub.subscription(config2.gcpPubSubSubscriptionName);

subscription.on('message', message => {
  storeEvent(message);
  message.ack();
});
```

setInterval works as expected when I remove this. Why is the above piece of code causing setInterval to mess up.

Here's my setInterval

```
let i =0
async function notificationQueue(){
  i++
  console.log('setInterval ran '+i)
}
setInterval(notificationQueue, 2000);
```

Comment: where is the setInterval ?¿

Comment: My setIntervals not the issue, it's the subscription.on portion of my code

Comment: Please notice `<>` icon in editor. You can create snippet that readers can run

Comment: `subscription.on` will only run your callback `message => { ... }` when the subscription emits the `message` event. Could it be that your callback isn't running as this is never emitted? You shouldn't need a `setInterval` here as the subscription will emit the `message` event when it receives data - `on` is attaching an event handler to this event.

Comment: Is there an error that causes it to not run?

Comment: @epascarello I'm not receiving any errors

Comment: @psilocybin These function don't really have much to do with each other. The message event runs whenever a sensor takes a reading.

Comment: Okay so interesting development, when I push the script to my heroku server instead of running it locally it works as expected...